# Why does the Number of names passed in does not match the number of header fields in the file(csv)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, jupyter-notebook

i want to read my csv file, with usecols format. I have written the contents of usecols according to the header in my csv file, here is the program code

```
TWEET_DATA = pd.read_csv("stemming.csv", usecols=['Id','clean'])
TWEET_DATA.columns = ["label", "tweet"]

TWEET_DATA.head()
```

[and here is my csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7BMM.png)

correct me if i'm wrong please help. Thank you

Comment: What is the output of `TWEET_DATA.columns` before you assign `TWEET_DATA` new columns?

Comment: there Id(number) and clean(contains some stemming in square brackets). You can see the link in the image I attached

Comment: What I wanted to ask is the output of `pd.read_csv("stemming.csv", usecols=['Id','clean']).columns`. It is probably something else than `Index(['Id', 'clean'], dtype='object')` considering it gives an AssertionError

Comment: I don't see a question here..? What are you trying to do?